# org.hibernate.MappingException: An AnnotationConfiguration instance is required to use <mapping class="entities.Employee"/>

Tags: java, hibernate, jersey, nhibernate-mapping

I Am Using HIbernate core 3.6.2 final. i put annotation class mapping in hibernate.cfg.xml  such as

And Since I use Hibernate version of 3.6.2 i dont need to create Annotation Configuration Class Object.
So I Create Configuration Object as
private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory;

```
static {
    try {

        sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure("hibernate.cfg.xml").buildSessionFactory();
    } catch (Throwable ex) {
        // Log the exception.
        System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
        throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
    }
}

public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
    return sessionFactory;
}
```

but is gives me error as
Initial SessionFactory creation failed.org.hibernate.MappingException: An AnnotationConfiguration instance is required to use 
org.hibernate.MappingException: An AnnotationConfiguration instance is required to use

My Pom. xml is as
http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    4.0.0
    com.tdm
    tdm
    war
    0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
    tdm Maven Webapp
    http://maven.apache.org
    
        
            junit
            junit
            3.8.1
            test

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.2.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.6-Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.0.ga</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>asm</groupId>
        <artifactId>asm</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>asm</groupId>
        <artifactId>asm-attrs</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
        <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.15</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.14</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.22.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>2.22.1</version>
    </dependency>


</dependencies>
<build>
    <finalName>tdm</finalName>
</build>
```

please help to solve my problem
my full stack trace is

```
Initial SessionFactory creation failed.org.hibernate.MappingException: An AnnotationConfiguration instance is required to use <mapping class="entities.Employee"/>
Feb 01, 2016 12:56:32 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [Jersey REST Service] in context with path [/tdm] threw exception [org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerException: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError] with root cause
org.hibernate.MappingException: An AnnotationConfiguration instance is required to use <mapping class="entities.Employee"/>
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.parseMappingElement(Configuration.java:1597)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.parseSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1552)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:1531)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:1505)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:1425)
    at model.HibernateUtil.<clinit>(HibernateUtil.java:20)
    at ws.EmployeeRestful.findAll_XML(EmployeeRestful.java:32)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory$1.invoke(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:81)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:144)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:161)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$TypeOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:205)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:99)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:389)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:347)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:102)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$2.run(ServerRuntime.java:326)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:317)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:305)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1154)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:471)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:425)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:383)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:336)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:223)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:521)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1096)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:674)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

Comment: care to give what is in there in "hibernate.cfg.xml"?

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate 3.6.2 doesn't generate such exception

`org.hibernate.MappingException: An AnnotationConfiguration instance is required to use <mapping class="entities.Employee"/>`

There is `hibernate-core` jar prior of 3.6.0 version in your classpath.  For an example `hibernate-core-3.5.0-Final.jar`.

Please, check jars like `hibernate3.jar` in the `lib` folder of your `war` or in the default `lib`folder (`#glassfish_home#/lib`) of your Glassfish application server.

Comment: i am using maven project. and and i add  all dependency in pom.xml. and i added this dependency <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.2.Final</version>
    </dependency>
but same error. if i change java version 1.7 then Description Resource 
Cannot change version of project facet Dynamic Web Module to 3.0. tdmserver

Comment: @Harshit Your `pom.xml` is correct. I think, something like `hibernate3.jar` comes to your classpath, when you deploy your application (for an example from default glassfish's lib folder).

Comment: @ v.ladynev I Am using Tomcat server . i am not using glassfish server.